# Formula in VBA based on adjusting cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm having some diffulculties in writing the right code. As you can see in the first picture I have 3 different stocks and the price of them listed in different columns.

[image: 1]

I now want to calculate the return of these different stocks, which I am doing by the use of VBA. The code refers to the sheet called "Input", but places the value in a different sheet. The last part of the code just drags the calculations to the last used column.

```
Range("B4").FormulaR1C1 = "=Input!R[1]C[1]/Input!R5C[1]*100"
lastcolumn = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
Range("B4").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(4, lastcolumn))
```

However, my problem occurs when dragging. As shown in the picture below, I can't drag the code due to the the number of columns in between the values in the "Input" sheet and that there are no columns inbetween in the other sheet. How can I change my code so VBA calculates the right way so the return of Microsoft i calculated by F5/F$5*100 and not D5/D$5*100? I hope the question makes sense.

[image: 2]

Comment: include images inline to help you better

Comment: They should be visible now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you have two alternatives:

1)adjust the autofill approach: write the formula in a loop, using an offset and then fill cells below

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("k2:m2")
Dim i As Integer
Dim offset As Integer
i = 0
offset = 2
For Each cell In rng
    cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Input!R[-1]C[-" & 10 - offset * i & "]/Input!R5C[-" & 10 - offset * i & "]*100"
    i = i + 1
Next cell
```

2) Modify the Bloomberg formula to hide dates (=bdh("AAPL UQ Equity","PX_LAST","dts=h") and that way all your price series are next to each other and that way your original autofill works

Comment: Thank you for the information about hiding the bloomberg dates, I did not know that. I have fixed the problem now.

Comment: Happy to help! Try to use Bloomberg sheet builder for even better results